# Does gmp lazy canonicalization with mpq_t?

Tags: performance, gmp

With gmp rationals, do I have the duty to bookkeep my calls to `canonicalize()` (which can be costly performance-wise)? Does gmp know that the rational was not changed since the last call to `canonicalize()` and will just return if I attempt canonicalization?

I cannot find an answer in the documentation, and maybe someone already looked into the source for this.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, does it? It is still unclear if two sequential calls to `canonicalize()` result in the same resource usage.

Comment: Source is visible here: https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpq/canonicalize.c . There is no shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It won't likely just return, as `mpq_t` does not contain any form of information whether fraction is already in canonical form or not. At least GMP documentation does not mention it as of [16.2 Rational Internals](https://gmplib.org/manual/Rational-Internals.html#Rational-Internals):

> `mpq_t` variables represent rationals using an `mpz_t` numerator and
>   denominator (see Integer Internals).

In practice, it will likely call `mpz_gcd()` (or equivalent), to check whether numerator and denominator are coprimes or not.